# Want the code to read ' instead of ’

Tags: python, json, csv, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a csv file to a json file. The whole code runs fine but when I encounter the statement: 
json.dump(DictName, out_file)
I get the following error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 15: invalid start byte

Would someone please be able to help?
TIA.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. The problem was not with the code but with the data present in my csv file. It wasn't taking the ' symbol properly, but that has left me hanging again. The data is full of symbols like ’ but I want my code to read ' instead of ’. Any suggestions would be really helpful..

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post just a few lines of code, as well as an example line from your CSV file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found the solution. While parsing the string, I converted the string to unicode using the unicode() function: unicode(stringname, errors='replace') and it replaced all the erroneous symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. While parsing the string, I converted the string to unicode using the unicode() function:

unicode(stringname, errors='replace')

and it replaced all the erroneous symbols.